# How to structure falcor router to get all available IDs?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I'm experimenting with using Falcor to front the [Guild Wars 2 API](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2]) and want to use it to show game item details. I'm especially interested in building a router that can use multiple datasources to combine the results of different APIs.

The catch is, [Item IDs](http://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items) in Guild Wars 2 aren't contiguous. Here's an example:

```
[
    1,
    2,
    6,
    11,
    24,
    56,
    ...
]
```

So I can't just write paths on the client like `items[100..120].name` because there's almost certainly going to be a bunch of holes in that list.

I've tried adding a route to my router so I can just request `items`, but that sends it into an infinite loop on the client. You can see that attempt [on GitHub](https://github.com/tivac/falcor-experiment/commit/9e5702704187d61559c87675f16eb2f2e53fc800).

Any pointers on the correct way to structure this? As I think about it more maybe I want `item.id` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't find your self asking for ids from a Falcor JSON Graph object.

It seems like you want to build an array of game ids:

```
{
    games: [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["gamesById", 352] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["gamesById", 428] }
        // ...
    ],
    gamesById: {
        352: {
            gameProp1: ...,
        },
        428: {
            gameProp2: ...
        }
    }
}

[games, {from: 5, to: 17 }, "gameProp1"]
```

Does that work?

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding how to use Falcor/JSON Graph, I probably am.

I want to show the first 100 items w/ their name/icon/price. It seems straightforward to ask my router for `items[1..100]['id', 'name', 'price']` but I'm tripping up on how to structure the server-side component so that it returns that correctly.

Comment: Needed to look more closely, a combination of `items.length` and `items` returning refs to a `itemsById` getter was the trick.

https://github.com/tivac/falcor-experiment/commit/8d2a3a6a08dab00c9689e6ac1aadfd7faea0df75

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'get' API of  Falcor, It retrieves multiple values.. You can pass any number of required properties as shown below

```
var model=new falcor.Model({
             cache:{       
                     genereList:[
                                    {name:"Recently Watched",
                                     titles:[
                                         {id:123,
                                          name: "Ignatius",
                                         rating: 4}
                                     ]    
                                    },
                                    {name:"New Release",
                                     titles:[
                                         {id:124,
                                          name: "Jessy",
                                         rating: 3}
                                     ]    
                                    }
                                ]
                            }

            });
            Getting single value
            model.getValue('genereList[0].titles[0].name').
            then(function(value){
               console.log(value);
           });

            Getting multiple values
            model.get('genereList[0..1].titles[0].name', 'genereList[0..1].titles[0].rating').
            then(function(json){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
            })
```